# Technologies to create a hybrid application in Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

This is not a programming question. If it is not appropriate to post it here, just advise me some place worth to share this.

What would be best to know in order to startup a project in Cordova. What i need to know is that in order to create a working web and android app what should i use?

So far

- I use Cordova.
- Ionic for GUI.
- PHP and MySQL for back end
- Angular JS for client side and controller for the app.
- JSON

Do I have to use AJAX as well? if so, where would it fit?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking here.  You *seem* to be asking which libraries you should use to build an app, but the way this is presented breaks multiple rules for making a question on-topic for this site.  Specifically, questions should have a **singular**, concrete answer possible;  suggestions, recommendations, etc. are all off-topic.  You seem to acknowledge this immediately in the question, but proceed to essentially ask us to recommend where else you can ask your question, which isn't really appropriate either.

Answer (score 1):

"Do I have to use AJAX as well? if so, where would it fit?"

Yes, you should build a Single Page Application inside Cordova using any framework that you desire.  Ionic/Angular is a valid choice here, other options include JQuery/Bootstrap, React JS, Framework7, OnsenUI and pretty much any combination of JS single page application framework and mobile focussed web front end framework that you like and can make work together.

For going beyond what the web view can do you'll use off the shelf plugins, or write your own which will need Java / Objective-C / C# or Swift skills depending on which platforms you're using.

As you want to be building a single page application you will need to make AJAX calls to get resources from servers, call APIs and the like.  Do this using the mechanism built into your chosen framework, e.g. $http service with Angular, $.ajax for JQuery etc.

Comment: Thanks and got it. But when it comes to $http I'm facing CORS and I'm working on it. If you don't mind can you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36887891/5850835) out and see what you can do to help me.

Answer (score 0):

With angular you can use AngularJS `$http`

Link to Angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: With $http I'm facing CORS and I'm working on it. If you don't mind can you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36887891/5850835) and see what you can do to help me.